# How do I choose a particular version of a FontAwesome icon?

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons, font-awesome

In FontAwesome there is a "bookmark" icon.

[image]

As you can see, they are both named "bookmark". But how do I choose between one and the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both have different classes 1st icon is something like `<i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i>` but for 2nd icon class is something like `<i class="far fa-bookmark"></i>`.

you need to pick from fas for solid, far for regular, fal for light, or fab for a brand.